# Is it possible to get BLE advertisement data from a Broadcast Receiver intent NAME_CHANGED?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

our BLE device advertises regularly its change through broadcasts.

The broadcast receiver with the intent filter android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED 
is correctly called.

But it does not contain advertisement data. Is it possible to get this advertisement data from this intent or another intent ?

Thks.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not get advertisement data from broadcast intent. Rather you need to scan for ble advertisers and the scan result will contain the advertisement data.

if you want to receive the notifications for advertised data, you need to connect and register for notifications on the specific characteristic of the service that other device is advertising.

you can follow the tutorial here.
[BLE tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

Comment: As it is broadcasted data, it should be available without connecting. Is it a limitation of the ble implementation in android os ?

Comment: yeah that is what i mentioned in the answer. The data would be available in the scan results. but for getting notified for changes on the data, you need to connect otherwise gatt server does not know whom to send the notification.

Comment: My hardware contact says he is transmitting informations in the advertisement, and told me to get it without connecting (ie without using GATT). So this is not possible using Android ...

Comment: alternate approach could be. Using the characteristics uuid make serial connection using rfcomm api to the device and read the data. This is not a gatt connection but normal spp connection. If you dont want to connect at all, then u can do frequent ble scan and read the values as the scan result also will contain all characteristics.

Comment: Ok lets connect as this seems the most simple. Will talk deeply to the hardware maker.